# MailChimp Subscriber Pop-up migrations with WordPress doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, mailchimp

When I input the generated code from MailChimp in WordPress header.php, I get only a blank page with pop up. Looks like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XP6z.png)

Blog posts are not displayed at all and return error in the console:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For >more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. embed.js:6

Code for migration that I upload in header.php is generated code which I got from MailChimp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us18.list-manage.com","uuid":"5f549f7042f16109ef402b18c","lid":"ce7c7591d1"}) })</script>
```

When I remove MailChimp migrations code from header.php everything works fine.When I input code for another form from MailChimp (except Subscriber Pop-up) everything looks fine.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm trying to find a solution for this. Will update this thread if I found anything.

Comment: This work for me. Try it. https://gist.github.com/nickcernis/3df74c0c6c18b75cb951